# How to decompose a permutation matrix into two-level unitary matrices?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, quantum-circuit

Assume a have a SBox and want to make quantum circuit for it. The unitary transform matrix for a SBox is special - a permutation matrix. I found an algorithm to decompose any unitary matrix into two-level unitary matrices.  But it's not optomized in this case.
So i wanna ask, is there any algorithm or any technique to decompose this permutation matrix in this special case into two-level unitary matrices. Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616889/worst-case-number-of-transpositions-needed-to-generate-a-permutation) might interest you.